# How to map multiple servlets in web.xml

Tags: java, html, netbeans

I'm attempting to have multiple servlets mapped in the web.xml. In my index.html, I have a form that actions "DeskType.do", and when I run the program it succeeds. I started out with this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>DeskType</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>controller.DeskType</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>DeskType</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/DeskType.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

...which worked just fine. It compiles successfully and upon pressing the button I have set up in index.html it runs as desired. After adding an additional servlet mapping:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>DeskType</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>controller.DeskType</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>DeskType</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/DeskType.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Servers</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/Servers.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

I received the error "The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details. BUILD FAILED (total time; 0 seconds)" I'm unsure what to do, as if I take this out it returns to working normally. Is there a correct way to set this up?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is very simple. You're missing new `<servlet-name>` and `<servlet-class>` tags. Here is the fix.

```
<!-- YOU"RE MISSING BELOW LINES AND CHANGE THE PACKAGE NAME 
       WHERE Servers CLASS IS PRESENT -->

<servlet>
    <servlet-name> <YOUR_SERVLET_NAME> </servlet-name>
    <servlet-class> <SERVLET_PACKAGE_NAME> </servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

Add the first 4 lines into your `web.xml` file. And replace `<YOUR_SERVLET_NAME>` and `<SERVLET_PACKAGE_NAME>` with your Servlet class name and it's package respectively.